# Why gmapping needs base_link → odom?

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my idea, the frame should be:

```
map->odom->base link->laser
```

[gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) says it needs:

```
<the frame attached to incoming scans> → base_link
    usually a fixed value, broadcast periodically by a robot_state_publisher, or a tf static_transform_publisher.
base_link → odom
    usually provided by the odometry system (e.g., the driver for the mobile base)
```

Why it just reverse?

Am I missing something?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81191/why-gmapping-needs-base_link-%E2%86%92-odom-?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The gmapping specification only requires the ability to transform data from the laser scan frame into the base_link frame and from the base_link into odom frame.  It does not specify the exact way that the frames are connected.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1